# How can I iterate the "<row></row>" tag in my XML file?

Tags: python, xml, csv

The below code will work just fine. However, the resulting xml will have each row tagged all the same for each record. I need this tag to be unique. My intent was to have the tag read <row 1></row 1>, <row 2></row 2>, ... I've commented out what I attempted but I get a type error when I try to run this in python. does anyone know a fix for this issue?

```html
import csv

csvFile = 'BySystem.csv'
xmlFile = 'BySystem.xml'

csvData = csv.reader(open(csvFile))
xmlData = open(xmlFile, 'w')
xmlData.write('<?xml version="1.0"?>' + "\n")


rowNum = 0
for row in csvData:
    if rowNum == 0:
        tags = row
        # replace spaces w/ underscores in tag names
        for i in range(len(tags)):
            tags[i] = tags[i].replace(' ', '_')
    else: 
       #xmlData.write('<row ' + rowNum + '>' + "\n")
        xmlData.write('<row>' + "\n")
        for i in range(len(tags)):
            xmlData.write('    ' + '<' + tags[i] + '>' \
                          + row[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n")
        #xmlData.write('</row ' + rowNum + '>' + "\n")
        xmlData.write('</row>' + "\n")
            
    rowNum +=1

xmlData.write('</csv_data>' + "\n")
xmlData.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rowNum` is `int`, you can not simply concatenate `str` with `int`, either convert `int` to `str` before concatenation that is replace

```
xmlData.write('<row ' + rowNum + '>' + "\n")
xmlData.write('</row ' + rowNum + '>' + "\n")
```

using

```
xmlData.write('<row ' + str(rowNum) + '>' + "\n")
xmlData.write('</row ' + str(rowNum) + '>' + "\n")
```

or use one kind of string formatting, e.g. so-called f-string (requires `python3.6` or newer)

```
xmlData.write(f'<row {rowNum}>\n')
xmlData.write(f'</row {rowNum}>\n')
```